# How can I replace n lines from a file to another file in C++?

Tags: c++, iostream

I want to replace the last n lines of first.txt with the first n lines of second.txt where n is input by the user. Here's my code:

```
ofstream myFirst("first.txt", ios:: binary);
ifstream mySecond("second.txt", ios::binary);
int firstFileLine = lineCountFirst;
int count = 0;
while(getline(myFirst, line)){
    count++;
    if(count >= firstFileLine){
        getline(mySecond, line2); // I don't know if it can be written like this
        line = line2;            // here to replace line to line2
    }
}
myFirst.close();
mySecond.close();
```

The two lines of code with comments are where I am confused about.
Any ideas about how to replace the file?

Comment: If you’re interested in lines don’t use `ios::binary`. Use `ios::text`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to replace the last n lines of first.txt with the first n lines of second.txt where n is input by the user.

Read `first.txt` in a `std::vector<std::string>` line by line. Remove the last `n` elements from the vector. Write the elements of the vector to a temporary file. Read `n` lines from `second.txt` and append them to the temporary file. Unlink `first.txt` and rename the temporary file you created.